# When I change data in element by id in array object, it duplicated to all elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, arrayobject

I just started using react.To store data, I use an array of objects. I specially created it of a certain length(100), so that using id to safely add user responses **(id is out of order, you can answer 1 and then 3)**. I wrote a function that adds a row to 0 array element (the array cannot be removed, it is used) But for some reason the value of the elements is duplicated for the entire array. Why does it happen and how to fix it???

**Variables**

```
  const [ans,setAns] =useState(Array(100).fill({
    Answer:[''],

}))
```

**Function**

```
 function SetWordAnswer(answer) {
    let next = [...ans];
    next[0].Answer[0] =answer
    setAns(next)
    console.log(next)
}
```

**Element in html**

```
   {VariableData.type === 'WordAnswer' ?
   <input placeholder="ответ" type="text" value={ans[variableId-1].Answer[0]} className="my-4 p-2 text-gray-50 bg-gray-900 rounded-full" onChange={(event)=>{SetWordAnswer(event.target.value)}}/>: ''}
```

**Used Data**
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NLrS.png)

**New Data after function**
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZZmg.png)

Comment: Your `.fill()` gives each member of the array the same object as its value.

Comment: Lol, it's true because of this, but how do I fill the array with empty elements like {Answer:['']} in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the array with a dummy value and then use `.map()` to fill it with *distinct objects* of the form you want:

```
const [ans,setAns] = useState(Array(100).fill(null).map(() => ({
    Answer:['']
})));
```

The elements will initially all *look* alike, but they will be distinct objects.